# Users using the Ask Password Option WSO2IS 5.9 REST API

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to implement wso2 user registration APIs. I found [REST APIs documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/apidocs/self-registration/), never find option to register "ask password option". But it is available in [SCIM 2.2](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/creating-users-using-the-ask-password-option/) and in Admin console.

I tried enabling SCIM APIs and tried ask password option sample

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data '{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"Smith","givenName":"Paul"},"userName":"Paul","password":"password","emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"paul@somemail.com"}],"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User":{askPassword:"true"}}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users
```

always getting 403 in postman

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Error 403</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Error 403 - Forbidden</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please check your admin user, user name and password currently you have added them as admin: admin

Comment: @BuddhimaUdaranga Thank you for your response, my admin username and password  are admin:admin. Is there any option in REST api to do the same?

Comment: Did you get any error logs in the carbon console? If so. please attach them as well

Comment: @PiraveenaParalogarajah Thank you,I implemented it with the help of SCIM.